# Using Mongoid (Ruby on Rails's MongoDB mapper), do we need to set a type if Cat inherits from Animal?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

that is, if `app/models/animal.rb` has

```
class Animal
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  field :birthday, :type => Time
end
```

and then in `app/models/cat.rb`

```
class Cat < Animal
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :nail_length, :type => Float
end
```

then do you need to set some kind of "type" in Animal to remember it is a Cat, or is it automatic?

Comment: highly recommend reading through the mongoid docs, they are very well written and easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

> An additional attribute _type is
>   stored in order to make sure when
>   loaded from the database the correct
>   document is returned. This also holds
>   true for the embedded documents
>   Circle, Rectangle, and Shape. Fields
>   and validations are inherited down the
>   hierachy, but not up. A subclass will
>   contain all of its parent's fields and
>   validations, but not vise-versa.

http://mongoid.org/docs/inheritance/